# How to have same backend for Flutter mobile app as of nodeJS website?

Tags: node.js, json, rest, flutter, ejs

I already have a website with nodeJS and EJS templating engine.  I know I should configure my server to return data in JSON format in order to have a backend for the flutter app.

I don't have much computer background and I'm a bit confused.

Here is what I'm doing in my website codes.

```
 router.get("/", (req, res) => {
 res.render("home", someData)
})
```

Comment: you can create a new route like `/api/` where you will serve `json`, or do you intend to sharee the same route between you webapp and flutter ?

Comment: I was thinking of the same route.

Comment: But if that's the only way, then I'll create a new route.

Comment: else you can return `json`, and use Flutter for your webapp and mobile, like that you will share the same code

[https://www.filledstacks.com/post/create-and-deploy-a-flutter-web-app/](https://www.filledstacks.com/post/create-and-deploy-a-flutter-web-app/)

Comment: you can use Dio or Http packages in Flutter in order to send request to your backend API.

Answer (score 1):

Just created different route for website and flutter application.

Route for website :

```
router.get("/api/web", (req, res) => {
    res.render("home", someData)
})
```

Route for mob-application :

```
router.get("/api/app", (req, res) => {
    //send response
})
```